# Preserving table selection in Word 2003 VBA macro

Tags: vba, ms-word, textselection

My goal is to write a VBA Macro for Word 2003, where the user selects part of a table (especially a column), and the macro maps input characters to specific output characters, e.g. any of *a e i o u* become *V*; some sequences like *eh uw* become *V*; one character (exclamation mark) is deleted; anything not turned into "V" is turned into "C". My problem is that after the first replace, the selection gets "unset", so changes affect something other than the original selection.

```
    With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Replacement.Text = "V"
            .Text = "[aeiouáéíóú]"
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
'replace certain sequences
            .Text = "[mn" & ChrW(618) & ChrW(650) & "]" & ChrW(769)
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Text = "[mn]" & ChrW(768)
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
'delete !
            .Text = "[\!]"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
'everything else becomes C
            .Text = "[!V]"
            .Replacement.Text = "C"
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
```

How do you get find/replace to only operate on the selected cells? I notice that after the first replace, Selection.End changes to the same value as Selection.Start. I do not understand how column selection works in Word.

Answer (score 0):

I created some macros to facilitate this. This will start an answer on how to move around columns.

```
Sub GoToTop()
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument      ' This takes the pointer to the body of the document ' place cursor the body of the document in case you are located on the header
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory 'key ctrl end
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory 'key ctrl end
End Sub


Sub GoToColumnTable() 'place cursor inside of the first column
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToTable
End Sub

Sub ColumnMove() 'move from one column to the other one
    Selection.Move Unit:=wdColumn, Count:=1
End Sub
Sub ColumnSelect() 'select the entire column in which the cursor is
    Selection.SelectColumn
End Sub
Sub ColumnDelete() 'delete a column that was selected
    Selection.Columns.Delete
End Sub
```